# Does this formula for the derivative of a differentiable inverse have a name?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, inverse-function, inverse-function-theorem

Consider the following lemma:

> Let $f:X \to Y$ be an invertible function, with inverse $f^{-1}:Y \to X$,and let $f(x_0) = y_0$. If $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$ and $f^{-1}$ is differentiable at $y_0$, then $$(f^{-1})'(y_0) = \frac{1}{f'(x_0)}.$$

This is introduced before the inverse function theorem in Tao's Analysis I, as a sort of precursor to the actual result. I am wondering if this lemma has a name, or if anyone has a good suggestion for a descriptive name to give it, just for my own personal notes.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem

Comment: I've only ever heard it referred to as the formula for the derivative of a function's inverse.

Comment: It's the Inverse function theorem in one dimension